# How to create a rule template that takes values from UI and creates drl files?

Tags: java, jersey, drools

I have taken values from a html page and set them to a java class. Now taking these values i have to create a rule template which dynamically creates drl files.
The rules should be like when i have productid=2 product=jwellery thendisplay mrp

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response)throws ServletException,IOException
{
String product=request.getParameter("t1");
int pid=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("t2"));
String city=request.getParameter("t3");
int cid=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("t4"));
int mrp=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("t5"));
float tax=Float.parseFloat("t6");
TemplateManager tm=new TemplateManager();
tm.setProduct(product);
tm.setPid(pid);
tm.setCity(city);
tm.setCid(cid);
tm.setMrp(mrp);
tm.setTax(tax);
}
```

Consider if i have this rule then what will be the template.

```
rule "price for medicines"
when
  item: Product(pid==1, pname=="Medicine")
then
  System.out.println( "Product ID="+item.getPid()+ "\tProduct Name="+ item.getPname()+ "\tMRP="+item.getMrp());
end
rule "price for groceries"
when
  item: Product(pid==2, pname=="Groceries")
then
   System.out.println( "Product ID="+item.getPid()+ "\tProduct Name="+item.getPname()+ "\tMRP="+item.getMrp());
end
```

Comment: Why do you need to "dynamically create DRL files"? On what would you base this creation?  Do you have a template for the rule? Your question leaves it wide open what you know and what you don't know.

Comment: Instead on manually creating drl files, i want a template that dynamically creates rules according to user input. The rule template is what i am asking for. How is it created

Comment: consider if i have this rule then what will be the template..

Comment: rule "price for medicines"
    
    when
       item: Product(pid==1,
                     pname=="Medicine")
     
     then
       System.out.println("Product ID="+item.getPid()+"\tProduct Name="+item.getPname()+"\tMRP="+item.getMrp());               
       
 end   
 
 rule "price for groceries"
 
     when
        item: Product(pid==2,
                      pname=="Groceries")
        
     then
          System.out.println("Product ID="+item.getPid()+"\tProduct Name="+item.getPname()+"\tMRP="+item.getMrp());
  end

Comment: Why don't you edit your question? One can't read this.

Answer (score 0):

The template below is taken, with minor modifications, from the Drools documentation which you might have read yourself.

```
template header
id
name

rule "price @{name} @{row.rowNumber}"
when
  item: Product(pid==@{id}, pname=="@{name}")
then
  System.out.println( "Product ID="+item.getPid()+ "\tProduct Name="+item.getPname()+ "\tMRP="+item.getMrp());
end
```

As it is, the rule is rather dull as it just prints Product data.

Comment: So will this this create a drl file or will it display the output directly because i want to create a drl file which will get the values.Sorry,I am very new to drools that's why having such problems.

Comment: This is just a template. You'll have to process it, providing data sets for id and name values. Then you'll have a DRL file with many rules,  which you can compile into rules and execute.

Comment: Last how to parse it?